# Angular controller $on only picks up when initialized within controller calling $broadcast

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events

I am trying to create a controller that picks up error messages and handles them:

```
ngLogin.controller('ErrorCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.$on('ngError', function(event, args) {
    $scope.displayErrors(args);
  });

  $scope.displayErrors = function(errors) {
    alert(errors);
  }
}]);
```

Other controllers are meant to broadcast errors like so:

```
ngLogin.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', 'LoginService', '$controller', '$rootScope', function($scope, LoginService, $controller, $rootScope) {
    $scope.login = function(callback) {
        LoginService.login($scope.user.username, $scope.user.password, function(token) {
            //SUCCESS
        }, function(errors) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('ngError', errors);
        });
    };
}]);
```

My problem is this does not work without the following code added to each of the broadcasting controllers:

```
$scope.ErrorCtrl = $scope.$new();
$controller('ErrorCtrl', {
    $scope: $scope.ErrorCtrl
});
```

index.html

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="../src/LoginService.js"></script>
<script src="../src/LoginCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="../src/ErrorCtrl.js"></script>
```

Is there not another way? I would prefer not to have to use the last piece of code in EVERY controller that needs this error handling. When I remove it the ErrorCtrl never receives the event.

Comment: It feels like there is something missing here.  If you have to initialize a new instance of the controller in order to broadcast, then it seems like the controller isn't mapped to the HTML properly.  But that doesn't explain how it works when you do initialize the instance....

Comment: looking at the code, it doesn't even look like you are mapping to HTML at all, and probably don't need a controller.  you should make a service instead, and inject the service into the controllers that need it.  Services are singletons, and don't need `$broadcast` to communicate with.

Comment: to clarify, when I suggest "not mapped to the HTML properly", I mean "there isn't an `ng-controller` for that controller".  This would make sense, given your code, since the code isn't actually writing HTML as much as calling a function.  This isn't the right place to use a controller.

Comment: That makes sense. So should I just inject the service into the controllers as I need them?

Comment: yes, exactly.  and the `displayErrors` function then doesn't go on `$scope` and you don't use `$broadcast`, you just call it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that create a service will be responsible for just showing an error messages & have a event listener code inside application run phase.

```
app.run(function($rootScope, errorService){
   //listner here
   $rootScope.$on('ngError', function(event, args) {
    $scope.displayErrors(args);
  });
});
app.service('errorService', function(){
   var errorService = this;
   errorService.displayErrors = function(errors){
       alert(errors)
   };
})
```

---

Or more convenient way would be just call service `displayErrors` method to display error messages whenever you want, by which you can eliminate events based approach from your application.

```
ngLogin.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', 'LoginService', '$controller', '$rootScope', 'errorService', function($scope, LoginService, $controller, $rootScope, errorService) {
    $scope.login = function(callback) {
        LoginService.login($scope.user.username, $scope.user.password, function(token) {
            //SUCCESS
        }, errorService.displayErrors); //call display error method here.
    };
}]);
```